# Transparent overlays with JMapViewer?

Tags: openstreetmap, jmapviewer

[JMapViewer](http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/JMapViewer) provides layers for displaying markers and other graphical elements on top of an OSM map. Is it also possible to use a (transparent) tile overlay on top of a basemap, i.e. to display more than one map at a time?